# Android Actionbar replacing fragment is called not showing anything

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am completely lost, how can something so simple be so hard to do? I have a MainActivity with a fragment (id:listfragment). When the activity start is show a list with newsitems. All i want to do is when a tab is selected is replacing the list with another. I was hoping this would be enough:

```
@Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        switch(tab.getPosition()) {

        case 0:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Tab News", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // News
            Fragment nfragment = new NewsList();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.listfragment, nfragment);
            break;

        case 1:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Tab Videos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // Videos
            Fragment vfragment = new YoutubeList();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.listfragment, vfragment);
        }

    }
```

The new fragments are called (i checked adding a Log) but no layout is shown. Will someone please put me out of my misery ;)

I tried adding .commit(). Crashes the app instantly. I understand that commit is automatically called (as they state in de Android docs) but i don't understand why it isn't showing anything.

Log after adding .commit():

```
03-01 09:43:00.736: D/dalvikvm(4509): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 79K, 14% free 10147K/11732K, paused 28ms, total 29ms
03-01 09:43:00.736: I/dalvikvm-heap(4509): Grow heap (frag case) to 12.450MB for 1127536-byte allocation
03-01 09:43:00.756: D/dalvikvm(4509): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 13% free 11248K/12836K, paused 19ms, total 19ms
03-01 09:43:00.776: D/AbsListView(4509): Get MotionRecognitionManager
03-01 09:43:00.821: D/AndroidRuntime(4509): Shutting down VM
03-01 09:43:00.821: W/dalvikvm(4509): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41a03700)
03-01 09:43:00.821: E/AndroidRuntime(4509): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-01 09:43:00.821: E/AndroidRuntime(4509): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.switchingbrains.xxx.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: commit already called
03-01 09:43:00.821: E/AndroidRuntime(4509):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2308)
03-01 09:43:00.821: E/AndroidRuntime(4509):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2362)
03-01 09:43:00.821: E/AndroidRuntime(4509):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:168)
03-01 09:43:00.821: E/AndroidRuntime(4509):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1329)
03-01 09:43:00.821: E/AndroidRuntime(4509):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-01 09:43:00.821: E/AndroidRuntime(4509):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-01 09:43:00.821: E/AndroidRuntime(4509):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5493)
03-01 09:43:00.821: E/AndroidRuntime(4509):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-01 09:43:00.821: E/AndroidRuntime(4509):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
03-01 09:43:00.821: E/AndroidRuntime(4509):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1209)
03-01 09:43:00.821: E/AndroidRuntime(4509):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1025)
03-01 09:43:00.821: E/AndroidRuntime(4509):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-01 09:43:00.821: E/AndroidRuntime(4509): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: commit already called
03-01 09:43:00.821: E/AndroidRuntime(4509):     at android.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:582)
03-01 09:43:00.821: E/AndroidRuntime(4509):     at android.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:574)
03-01 09:43:00.821: E/AndroidRuntime(4509):     at com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl.selectTab(ActionBarImpl.java:608)
03-01 09:43:00.821: E/AndroidRuntime(4509):     at com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl.addTab(ActionBarImpl.java:532)
03-01 09:43:00.821: E/AndroidRuntime(4509):     at com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl.addTab(ActionBarImpl.java:518)
03-01 09:43:00.821: E/AndroidRuntime(4509):     at com.switchingbrains.xxx.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:29)
03-01 09:43:00.821: E/AndroidRuntime(4509):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
03-01 09:43:00.821: E/AndroidRuntime(4509):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
03-01 09:43:00.821: E/AndroidRuntime(4509):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2270)
03-01 09:43:00.821: E/AndroidRuntime(4509):     ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you define a fragment in the xml with the fragment tag, you can`t replace it at runtime. Try with a FrameLayout instead and use the same id.

You probably have something like this:

```
<fragment ....
          android:id="@+id/listfragment"
          ....  />
```

Change it to this:

```
<FrameLayout ....
             android:id="@+id/listfragment"
             ....  />
```

Comment: Please include an example, this answer is too short and more of a comment.

Comment: No problem +1 for including the example :)

Comment: The example saved the day! Thanks a lot!